# Haskell -- Generate Coordinates From Ends of the Path

Tags: haskell

I have an input of `[ ( (Int,Int) , (Int,Int) ) ]` which is the coordinate of the ends of the path. All paths run either horizontally (same y-value for both ends) or vertically (same x-value for both ends).
So I want to write a function that generates all the coordinates of the path from the input.

For example, the input pair of ends is `[((0, 0), (0, 3)), ((0, 2), (2, 2))]`(this is two paths), the output of the function I need is `[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)], [(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)]]`

```
getPaths :: [ ( (Integer,Integer) , (Integer,Integer) ) ] -> [[(Integer,Integer)]]
getPaths [((xa, ya), (xb, yb))]   
    | xa == xb : [(xa, yb + 1) | yb < ya]++
    | xa == xb : [(xa, ya + 1) | ya < yb]++
    | ya == yb : [(xa + 1, ya) | xa < xb]++
    | ya == yb : [(xb + 1, ya) | xb < xa]++
```

I'm not sure if its right, could anyone have a look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to first make a function that works with a single pair of coordinates:

```
path :: ((Int, Int), (Int, Int)) -> [(Int, Int)]
path = …
```

then `getPaths` is just a mapping of this:

```
getPaths :: [((Int, Int), (Int, Int))] -> [[(Int, Int)]]
getPaths = map path
```

as for the `path`, you can make use of ranges, indeed `[x₁ .. x₂]` will produce all (integral) values between `x₁` and `x₂` (both inclusive).

The function thus can be constructed with list comprehension with:

```
path :: ((Int, Int), (Int, Int)) -> [(Int, Int)]
path ((x₁, y₁), (x₂, y₂)) = [ … | … <- …, … <- … ]
```

where you still need to fill in the `…` parts.

Comment: Does the order matter in `[x₁ .. x₂]`?

Comment: @Rara: yes, it will only work if `x₁` is less than or equal to `x₂`, hence you will need to find a solution for this issue.